# Java DateFormat returning incorrect Date

Tags: java, date, date-parsing

I am trying to parse a date with a `SimpleDateFormat` and I encountered a strange behavior.

This Example prints `"Sun Jan 01 19:00:32 CET 2012"` on my machine:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Sep 26 19:00:32 2012"));
    }
}
```

I would expect to have `"Wed Sep 26 19:00:32 CET 2012"` returned instead.

Is my DateFormat String incorrect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The year uses small caps `y`:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).
            parse("Sep 26 19:00:32 2012"));
```

Large cap `Y` is "Week year" [according to javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the answer. Silly oversight really. I'll mark the answer as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: This broke the Twitter API today.

Answer (score 2):

Use `yyyy` (lowercase) instead of `YYYY` (uppercase). `Y` is the *Week year*; whilst `y` is the *year*.

Also note that the `Y` pattern was only introduced in **Java 7**, which can explain why you are seeing an error. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> If week year 'Y' is specified and the calendar doesn't support any
>   week years, the calendar year ('y') is used instead. The support of
>   week years can be tested with a call to
>   getCalendar().isWeekDateSupported().

Using Java 7, and with a `GregorianCalendar`, your code works just fine, as you can see in this **[demo](http://ideone.com/vPkSO)**.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with date parsing not formatting. Try passing new Date() in the parse, see the result and change format accordingly.